# Adding objects from one class to an ArrayList in another class

Tags: java, object, arraylist, addition

I'm new to java and I'm trying to write my first "bigger" program, with several classes. I have created an ArrayList in the class "CompetitionProgram" and it's declared as private.

```
public class CompetitionProgram {
```

`private ArrayList<ListOfEvents> eventList = new ArrayList<ListOfEvents>();`

In the method "addEvent", I'm creating an object of the class Event:

```
    private void addEvent() {

    System.out.print("Event name: ");
    String eventName = checkInput();

    System.out.print("Attempts allowed: ");
    int noOfAttempts = readInt();

    Event ev = new Event(eventName, noOfAttempts);
    eventList.add(ev);
```

Event-class:

```
public class Event {

private String eventName;
private int noOfAttempts;

public Event(String eventName, int noOfAttepmts) {
    this.eventName = eventName;
    this.noOfAttempts = noOfAttepmts;
}

public String getEventName() {
    return eventName;
}

public int getNoOfAttempts() {
    return noOfAttempts;
}
```

ListOfEvents-class (It's not finished, I know I can't return "event" etc):

```
public class ListOfEvents {
public ListOfEvents() {

}

public Event addEvent(eventName, noOfAttempts) {
    // code  -add event to the list
    // code
    return event;
}

public Event findEvent(eventName) {
    // code -check if event already is in the list
    // code
    return event;
}

public boolean isEvent(eventName) {
    //code  -check if input is empty
    //code
    return true or false;
}
```

I want to add the Event object to the declared ArrayList at the top, but I can't because the ArrayList is a list of the class "ListOfEvents". So, my problem is to add Event objects to the ArrayList of the class ListOfEvents.

I need both of these classes (Event & ListOfEvents) in my program, it's one of the requirements. *Event* - that just represents the event itself like event name and number of attempts (its a sports event). And *ListOfEvents* - that represents the  list itself and contains methods for adding events, removing events and checking if the event is already in the list etc.

Anyone who has any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Post ListOfEvents as well. Names are misleading here. ListOfEvents should probably contain a list , not be the class added to the list.

Comment: `ListOfEvents list = new ListOfEvents(); list.add(ev); eventList.add(list);`

Answer (score 0):

You mean to create a list of "list of events". 
If so, the following code would work fine.

```
ListOfEvents list = new ListOfEvents();
Event ev = new Event(eventName, noOfAttempts);
list.add(ev);
eventList.add(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, if i miss something, but i think, there is a simple solution:

--> Just change the generic type of the ArrayList from "ListOfEvents" to "Event":

```
private ArrayList<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
```

This creates a scalable list of single instances of the type "Event".

So, as an illustrating example, the following snippet would create an ArrayList of single Strings:

```
private ArrayList<String> eventList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Or do want to create lists of lists of "Events"? As you said, it is about sport events. Therefore maybe you want to create games, built with events, and add these games to a list. In this case you work this way:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Event>> eventList ...
```